# Does Doxygen look at the source file names while generating the pdf?

Tags: doxygen

I have very starnge behavior with doxygen. I have source file named as Float32Add.c, when i try to generate the pdf document using doxygen, the documentation does not appear. When i change the same source file name(.c), for e.g. try.c the documentation inside the source file appears (I didnt modify anything except the src file name). I also verified length of the source file is not a problem. Is there any property thats i can look and it helps. Any help regarding this would be appreciated

Comment: By default doxygen does not exclude file names. Please give some more details / short project / Doxyfile.

Comment: Thanls for your reply.                                                                        Does doxygen has some problem in having the source files names starting with float something like that. As my problem is really weird. It works for all the other source files without float but not something which has float in its name.

Comment: I'm not aware of such a restriction and I could not reproduce it on Windows either. Which OS are you using? Can you create a small example showing the problem?